# Read/Write json objects from Postgres database through cache

Tags: json, postgresql, ignite, jsonb

I'm working with read/write through the cache via Apache Ignite and encountered the following problem:

In lastest versions of postgres there is special json type of data and jsonb add-on to work with json in database.

In Apache Ignite this functions don't implemented, how I know. Moreover, when Trying to do this part, I found it possible to read json from the database as PGobject, but there is no way to add jsonb processing to the built-in SQL query parser.

For example, I'm trying send next query:

```
SELECT jdata->>'tag1' FROM jsontest;
```

And get exception:

> Syntax error in SQL statement "`SELECT JDATA-[*]>>'tag1' FROM JSONTEST;` "; SQL statement:
>   `SELECT jdata->>'tag1' FROM jsontest;` [42000-195]
>
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
>   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
>   at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:191)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:533)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.getSpecialType(Parser.java:3842)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.read(Parser.java:3352)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.readIf(Parser.java:3259)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2375)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2341)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2172)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2144)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2136)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleSelectPart(Parser.java:2047)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2079)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1934)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1749)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1737)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:448)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:320)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:296)
>   at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:257)
>   at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:573)
>   at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:514)
>   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
>   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
>   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
>   at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:402)
>   at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1365)
>   ... 9 more

And when I'm trying to research structure of Ignite or H2 databse engine, there is no way to add processing of such queries.

So, maybe someone has met this or a similar problem and can advise how to solve it?

Comment: Looks a bit like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem you're solving with JSON stored in RDBMS? Why do you need its support in Ignite?

Comment: It will be used in implementation of [AQL](http://www.openehr.org/releases/QUERY/latest/docs/AQL/AQL.html), where needs to combine standart SQL with xml/json quering. Moreover, in this usecase expected heavy files, so it necessary to use in-memory tech

Comment: Ignite does not support JSON queries at the moment. If you cannot convert your data to structured SQL, I think the best way would be to send a computation to a node, extract the whole JSON locally on that node (so there are no extra network trips) and then use standard JSON search tools to find the required data.